# Android scrollview doesn't with with relative layout in landscape mode

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to make an Android view scroll when it's in landscape orientation. However, this does not work on any device I've tried it with. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Here's my markup:

```
    <ScrollView
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/sample1"
       android:gravity="top" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent">
       <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/sample1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
      </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:id="buttons" 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:padding="3dp">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: There is an additional linear layout that's being included into this view. I believe this may be the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: there isn't nothing wrong at your xml seeing no the fly, why do you say that doesn't work in any device, maybe you can post the error what LogCat throws...

Comment: Can you see if you have a `layout-land` file in your `res/layout-land/YOUR_FILE_NAME` and you have a different layout for each (portrait/landscape) mode,

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this code. I've tried it with an `768x1024` jpg which was placed in the mdpi drawable folder. What is the resolution of the image that youve used ? Are you sure you have no TextViews or other views embedded in your layout ?

[image]

Comment: My mistake. There is a linear layout holding a set of buttons that's being pulled into the bottom of the page with an include. <LinearLayout
 android:id="buttons"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:padding="3dp">